# cross dependencies in composer require

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, composer-php

Im trying to require `phpunit/dbunit`.

I run the command `php composer.phar require phpunit/dbunit` which apparently requires `symfony/yaml ^3.0`.

My problem is I already have a vendor library that uses `symfony/yaml v2.8.33`.

Here is the composer log:

```
Installation request for phpunit/dbunit 3.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/dbunit[3.0.0].
- Conclusion: remove symfony/yaml v2.8.33
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.33
- phpunit/dbunit 3.0.0 requires symfony/yaml ^3.0
```

My issue is if i install `symfony/yaml ^3.0` wont this  break my existing dependency that is using `symfony/yaml v2.8.33`.

I want the latest version of `phpunit/dbunit` so installing an earlier version is not really what I'm seeking.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

If the phpunit package explicitly requires a version of a package which you explicitly installed in another version, there is no real good solution. You could try to update your code to use Symfony 3.0, as this should be the same as 2.8 without deprecation notices, and then installing dbunit should be possible.